# Primeface 10 Datatable filter function is doing a copy of my object

Tags: filter, datatable, primefaces

i updated from PF8 to PF10 last week and there are some problems i got.
Currently i have a big problem with my DataTable. Im showing a list of users, where i can open a dialog to edit them. After saving im closing the dialog and make a update on the table to see the changes.
And here is my problem: somehow the tables is showing the old values. After debugging i saw the setter got a copy of the selected object. im using eclipse and the object-id was a different then the original object, so i know its a copy.

These are things i tested:

1. Open the Page, click button for edit (debugging is showing the right objectid), do something and save+hide+update table -> Table showing the changes. I can do this multiple times and everytimes its working fine.
2. Open Page, use a filter (simple contains-filter for a name) , click buton for edit (debugging shows a different objectid), do something and save+hide+update table -> Table showing the old changes. Now everytime im using the button to edit i see a different object id in debugger.
3. Open Page, use a filter, put a breakpoint inside the lib for checking if the right object is added to the values to show. Filter got the right object (right objectid) but after clicking the button somehow i got a copy.

This is my datatable:

```
    <p:dataTable var="m" id="mitID" widgetVar="mitTable" 
                value="#{meineDaten.allmlist}" filteredValue="#{meineDaten.filtermlist}"
                rowStyleClass="#{m.ausgeschieden ? 'ausgeschieden':''}">
```

my editbutton:

```
   <p:column  exportable="false" width="28" style="text-align:center">
                      <p:commandButton disabled="#{m.typ eq 'SERVICE' and me.typ ne 'SERVICE' || not me.findRecht('Editor','Basisdaten-Stammdaten-Mitarbeiter')}" id="bearbeiten" update=":mitformID"  icon="ui-icon-pencil" styleClass="old" style="width:23px;height:23px;border:none"
                    oncomplete="PF('mitDialog').show()">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{m}"
                                    target="#{meineDaten.selectedmit}" />
                                <f:ajax />
                </p:commandButton></p:column>
```

In PF8 its working fine, but im not sure if its a PF10 problem because it tested it inside the showcase and its working fine too. Is there some web.xml settings i need to do?

Hoping my english is understandable

Thanks for reading and maybe helping :)

Comment: Try to post a fully reproducible example, else it's hard to tell what isn't working. The problem is that updating your data table, while is filtered, show wrong/duplicate data?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: i tried to build a example inside the PF-Showcase but somehow its working fine. I updated now JSF to 2.3 and need to change my JSF container to CDI, because ManagedBean is now deprecated. Maybe after rebuild everything,  my problem will be solved.